# Transformar un variable String en Java

Tags: java, string

Tengo la siguiente variable:

[image: Declaración de la variable]

Si la imprimo la salida es:

[image: Salida del valor de la variable]

Cuando en realidad lo que busco es imprimir literalmente cada carácter que conforma la cadena:

[image: Salida del valor de la cadena]

Lo he intentado con *Pattern*:

```
Pattern.compile(c,Pattern.LITERAL);
```

Y también he usado:

```
Pattern.quote()
```

Pero aun no logro mi objetivo, ¿alguna sugerencia?, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es imprimir el texto tal cual necesitas escapar algunos caracteres de esta manera.

```
String regex = "([+\\-!\\(\\){}\\[\\]^\"~*?:\\\\]|[&\\|]{2})";

String myStringToEscape = "ABC^ \" ~ * ? :DEF";
String myEscapedString = myStringToEscape.replaceAll(regex, "\\\\$1");

System.out.println(myEscapedString);
```

Comment: No, no quiero eso, de hecho quiero tomar los caracteres que están el definición de la cadena de manera literal es decir que no ademas de imprimir las " imprima el \, pero gracias de todas formas.

Comment: @MAngelambrose Actualicé la respuesta, ojalá te sirva 

Comment: Gracias si me sirvió, pero, ¿Que quiere decir el segundo argumento del replaceAll ?

Comment: Es un backreference para mantener los que no necesitan reemplazarse

Answer (score 2):

Hola si lo que quieres es tambien imprimir la barra(\) debes escribirlo del siguiente modo

```
String c="\\\"cadena\\\"";
System.out.println(c);
```

Con esto ya podras imprimir tambien las barras sean del estilo "\" o "/"

Otra forma es con el codigo ascii del caracter que quieres

Suerte